# How to change 'Response Headers "cache-control" '

Tags: joomla-3.x, cache, cache-handler, header-tags

I have got a site running on AWS using Cloudfront which is caching the site.

I've got browser and page cache enabled in Joomla.

However, when looking at the Response Headers, under cache control it's showing as "no-cache" and under "x-cache" it's showing as "Miss from cloudfront"

It appears that Cloudfront is being told (by Joomla) to not cache the site.

Any ideas on how I can control the headers? I've used 'Expires Headers' plugin but it's still not showing the cache.

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue with "Expires Headers" installed and configured. Headers could also be set by your server or even by CDN itself.